# Yosemite recognize only 1.6.0.jdk even though I installed Java 8. I can't modify java_home

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I've uninstalled Eclipse on Mac OS X (Yosemite) and now I can't install neither Eclipse nor Jboss developer studio because Mac OS X Yosemite recognizes only 
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home 
even if I've installed the latest Java VM.

I've verified

[image]
<sub>(source: [thekokeformula.com](http://thekokeformula.com/verified.png))</sub>

if i do on terminal this

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V it
```

answers

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

It can't see I've updated Java.

If I try this:

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8'
```

nothing happens.

Could you help me?

Comment: The JVM you installed - are you sure it was the JDK, rather than the JRE? Where did you go to install it?

Comment: yes i've installed from here    http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: If that's the response you get from `/usr/libexec/javahome -V`, then the installation failed. Download the file again and run the installation again, be watchful and make sure that it accepts your admin password when you type it.

Comment: thank you, i've installed and reinstalled many times but this time was successful, now it works thank you

Answer (score 2):

First, verify that the JDK was installed in the correct location by running this:

```
$ ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
```

You should see:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk
```

If you don't see that, you may have installed a JRE, which doesn't install here for unknown reason. If you installed via the Java self-update mechanism, it never seems to work properly. Your best bet on Mac OS X is to always download the full Java JDK from Oracle here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

But even if you can't set your Java home at the OS level, you can set it from within Eclipse by going to Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs and explicitly add the JRE.

Comment: yes i've installed from here    http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.htm

Comment: I installed the JDK, as you suggested, and everything works now. Many thanks!!

Comment: This worked for me. Turns out I installed the JRE instead of the JDK. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all the existing java IDE related files, and then reinstall. Or try a portable IDE.

Comment: What do you mean by "Java IDE related files" or a "portable IDE"? This is an issue with the JDK installation.

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE... also, portable IDE does not need an installed JDK as it come bundled with one.

Comment: do you mean to delete java folder from Library?  so /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
become  /System/Library/ ???

Comment: Dont delete it, move it to your desktop or something in case it breaks something important. and then try and install.

Answer (score 0):

Your export statement should have backticks (shift + tilde key) instead of single quotes so that you execute the '/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8' statement

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```